# How to create custom event directive that have $event like ng events

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have AngularJS directive like this:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    // better click that ingore drag
    angular
        .module('module')
        .directive('exClick', exClick);

    exClick.$inject = [];
    function exClick() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
              exClick: '&'
            },
            link: function ($scope, $element) {
                var isDragging = false;
                function mousemove() {
                    isDragging = true;
                    $(window).off('mousemove', mousemove);
                }
                var timer;
                $element.mousedown(function() {
                    isDragging = false;
                    // there is wierd issue where move is triggerd just
                    // after mousedown even without moving the cursor
                    timer = setTimeout(function() {
                        $(window).mousemove(mousemove);
                    }, 100);
                }).mouseup(function(e) {
                    var wasDragging = isDragging;
                    isDragging = false;
                    clearTimeout(timer);
                    $(window).off('mousemove', mousemove);
                    if (!wasDragging) {
                        $scope.$apply($scope.exClick);
                    }
                });

                $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
                    $(window).off('mousemove', mousemove);
                    $element.off('mousedown mouseup');
                });
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

and I want to use like normal ng event I have ng-click on table row and on row controls I have `ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()"`. I've replaced row with ex-click and I want to use `ex-click="$event.stopPropagation()"`. I can use ng-mouseup to prevent the event from happening, but I want to know how to make my custom event to behave the same as native ng event.

I've tried:

```
$scope.exClick({$event: e});
```

and

```
$scope.$event = e;
$scope.$apply();
$scope.exClick();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found in the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/dedb10c0b89a92f5c43b4c4d3f1054cd8179a58e/src/ng/directive/ngEventDirs.js) ngClick is kind of normal AngularJS directive (it's added differently but it have the same compile and link, so it should work the same).

And for reference here is the copy of the code:

```
forEach(
  'click dblclick mousedown mouseup mouseover mouseout mousemove mouseenter mouseleave keydown keyup keypress submit focus blur copy cut paste'.split(' '),
  function(eventName) {
    var directiveName = directiveNormalize('ng-' + eventName);
    ngEventDirectives[directiveName] = ['$parse', '$rootScope', '$exceptionHandler', function($parse, $rootScope, $exceptionHandler) {
      return createEventDirective($parse, $rootScope, $exceptionHandler, directiveName, eventName, forceAsyncEvents[eventName]);
    }];
  }
);

function createEventDirective($parse, $rootScope, $exceptionHandler, directiveName, eventName, forceAsync) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    compile: function($element, attr) {
      // NOTE:
      // We expose the powerful `$event` object on the scope that provides access to the Window,
      // etc. This is OK, because expressions are not sandboxed any more (and the expression
      // sandbox was never meant to be a security feature anyway).
      var fn = $parse(attr[directiveName]);
      return function ngEventHandler(scope, element) {
        element.on(eventName, function(event) {
          var callback = function() {
            fn(scope, {$event: event});
          };

          if (!$rootScope.$$phase) {
            scope.$apply(callback);
          } else if (forceAsync) {
            scope.$evalAsync(callback);
          } else {
            try {
              callback();
            } catch (error) {
              $exceptionHandler(error);
            }
          }
        });
      };
    }
  };
}
```